# java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file while having whitespace in url path

Tags: java

I have a URL, which contains a white-space in middle, When I invoke the new JarFile() constructor on this file, I am getting an exception "java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file"

I am trying the following url

```
URL url = file:/usr/local/mvn%20repo/javax/persistence/persistence-api/2.0/persistence-api-2.0.jar
```

and creating JarFile object

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(url.getFile());
```

and getting error following error:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
```

Thanks 
 KK

Comment: You probably get a more verbose error than this, right? Stacktrace?

Comment: Try this: URL url = URLDecoder.decode("file:/usr/local/mvn%20repo/javax/persistence/persistence-api/2.0/persistence-api-2.0.jar", "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\s","");

Comment: Yes, `URLDecoder.decode` is needed to replace `%20` with a space. Bah.

Answer (score 1):

Try file:// as the protocol. So in total it would contain 3 slashes and look like this:

```
file:///usr/local/mvn%20repo/javax/persistence/persistence-api/2.0/persistence-api-2.0.jar
```